# Azure WebJob using lxml keeps failing...why?

Tags: python, azure, lxml, azure-webjobs

I am new to Azure and Python and am trying to run a Python script as a webjob in Azure. I know that I need to include all the package files in the webjob, but I think that I am missing some dependencies which is causing the error. Here is the error log:

```
[01/28/2015 03:53:29 > 52e03f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[01/28/2015 03:53:35 > 52e03f: SYS INFO] Run script 'get_teams_espn.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[01/28/2015 03:53:35 > 52e03f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]   File "get_teams_espn.py", line 45, in <module>
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]     teams_dict = teams_espn(url)
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]   File "get_teams_espn.py", line 23, in teams_espn
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]   File "site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
[01/28/2015 03:53:36 > 52e03f: ERR ]     % ",".join(features))
[01/28/2015 03:53:37 > 52e03f: ERR ] bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
[01/28/2015 03:53:37 > 52e03f: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[01/28/2015 03:53:37 > 52e03f: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

Here re my imports:

```
import sys  
sys.path.append("site-packages")

import csv
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

What other packages do I need to make this script work? Or did I not set up my script to find the package files? Please help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you don't have `lxml` module installed.

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb, but what do you mean? I have `lxml` in the packages I loaded with the scriot an I'm importing it in my code. Is there something else I need to do or is my code not importing it correctly?

Comment: Is lxml in your requirements.txt file and installed on the azure machine?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to employ python packages that can not directly be build in the Azure environment. That is for instance if you want to include packages relying on the `lxml` binds. this issue can be resolved by telling the Azure environment directly to install from wheels files rather than download a remote resource and compiling it.

Create a folder 'wheelhouse':

```
mkdir wheelhouse
```

Obtain the suitable `lxml` wheels binary file from [Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and copy it to the 'wheelhouse' directory. For me the version 
`lxml-3.6.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl` did the job. 
I had to rename `lxml-3.6.0-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl` into `lxml-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl` to function properly. Lastly, make sure to include in the `requirements.txt` the following from line 1:

```
--no-index
--find-links wheelhouse
lxml==3.6.0
otherWheelsFile_pre-compiled==1.x.x
```

The first line tells pip in the deployment to not check for remote sources and the second line tells where to look for installing packages.

I also created wheels files locally for the packages relevant to the web app. It is important that all dependencies are resolved and wheels files are put into the `wheelhouse` directory.